# How to set component at end of Row in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set RadioButton component at the end of Row in Jetpack Compose. Tried to using Constraint Layout and moved RadioButton outside the Row but then the RadioButton wasn't centered with other components in Row. What should I do?
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    ConstraintLayout {
        val (row, button) = createRefs()
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(56.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .constrainAs(row){
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Icon(
                /* *** */
            )
            Text(
                text = "mail@gmail.com",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
            )
            RadioButton(
                /* *** */
            )
        }

    }
```

What is more i want to cut the Text component if the text is too long (not overlay or underlay the Radio Button)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972289/3585796) answer your question?

Comment: @PylypDukhov yes, it's the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

The simplest solution would be to add a `Spacer` with `Modifier.weight(1f)` between your text and the radio button. `Row` and `Column` distribute remaining available space between components with a `weight` Modifier according to their weight. Since there is only one, it will receive all of the remaining space, pushing the radio button to the far right.

For example following code would produce your desired behavior:

```kotlin
Row(modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp).fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
    Icon(Icons.Default.Add,null)
    Text("Some text here")
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxHeight().background(Color.Green)) // height and background only for demonstration
    RadioButton(selected = false, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
}
```

[image]

As I said remaining space is distributed according to the weight of each element, so although this is not what you want to achieve, an example how this might look like

```kotlin
Row(modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp).fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    Icon(Icons.Default.Add, null)
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxHeight().background(Color.Red)) // height and background only for demonstration
    Text("Some text here")
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(4f).fillMaxHeight().background(Color.Green)) // height and background only for demonstration
    RadioButton(selected = false, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
}
```

will get you

[image]

The remaining space after measuring the icon, text and radio button are distributed as 20% to the red Spacer and 80% to the green one, since that is their share of the total weight (1/5 and 4/5)

Comment: Unfortunately, after using this solution, the buttons are not positioned in one line (depending on the length of the text)

Comment: @AndroideuszPL Constrain the text to be single line

Comment: No need for a spacer. Add the appropriate paddings to the start and end items in the row. Then add the Weight(1f) modifier to the Text composable itself. The Text is left aligned and will wrap by default, and the weight will cause it to occupy any remaining space in the Row so the length of the text won't affect the overall layout. All the leading icons and Radiobuttons will then have identical spacing and alignment.