# Unable to design UI Layout in Desktop for Compose

Tags: kotlin, layout, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I am developing UI Layout for an app based on [Compose for Desktop](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/)

It consist of few check boxes.
But there is no functionality in [Compose for Desktop](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Getting_Started) to align views to each other.

In Android, we can use the `Constraint Layout` for view alignment and it is super easy.
But what to do for Compose for Desktop?
Here is the layout I need to design in Desktop Compose

[image: UI Layout Design]

And here is the code I have written in `Main.kt` file:
But the output is very different.
Would you please guide as there are no official documentation/videos for Compose For Desktop Layout Alignment and sizing ?

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme(
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints {
            TwoColumnsLayout()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TwoColumnsLayout() {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.4f), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            LeftPaneContent()
            Divider(
                color = Color.Blue,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(1.dp)
            )
        }
        RightPaneContent()
    }
}

@Composable
fun LeftPaneContent() {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "Left Pane First Text Box")
        Text(text = "Left Pane Second Text Box")
        Column {
            Text(text = "Left Pane Radio button Box  ", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp))
            val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
        }
        Text(text = "Left Pane bottom Text Box")
    }
}

@Composable
fun RightPaneContent() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Column(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "Right Pane First Text Box")
            Text(text = "Right Pane Second Text Box")
            Text(text = "Right Pane Third Text Box")
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        state = WindowState(size = DpSize(1440.dp, 768.dp))
    ) {
        App()
    }
}
```

I do not need the complete code.
I just need help with the view placement, alignment  and sizing as per the above design.
I am unable to create a UI layout as shown in above image and also there are no documentation around Compose For Desktop UI Layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` is what you need in quite rare cases, in most cases Compose Layout is enough.

You can check out the Compose Layout [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts), which I think is rich with examples of a similar layout - at least parts of it.

You just have a lot of errors in your code, but the general approach is correct. With a little practice, you'll start having a lot more fun with it than with `ConstraintLayout`.

1. `TwoColumnsLayout` - it's not quite clear why you decided to put the left content and separator in `Box` - it will place them one above the other. Just remove the `Box` and leave the content.
2. The `Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.4f)` can be moved right into the `LeftPaneContent` - add `fillMaxHeight` and remove `fillMaxSize`. Alternatively, you can create a `Modifier` parameter so it can be controlled from `TwoColumnsLayout`.
3. Use `Modifier.weight(1f)` only for one child in `Row`/`Column` so it take all space available after other views layout - more info can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972289/3585796).
4. `LeftPaneContent` - according to your design you probably need to put the first two texts in `Row` if you want them to be the same size - add `Modifier.weight(1f)` to each.
5. `RightPaneContent` - same as in point 3: you probably need to put the second and third views in `Row`. `Box` with a single child is redundant and can be removed.
6. `BoxWithConstraints` inside `App` is also not used and can be removed.

Also use `Spacer` to add spacing between views and `Modifier.padding` as needed. Also a good practice is moving using modifier as the last parameter - in this case you don't have to deal with the trailing comma when you need to add/reorder modifiers.

This should be much closer to your expected layout:

```
@Composable
fun TwoColumnsLayout() {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LeftPaneContent()
        Divider(
            color = Color.Blue,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(1.dp)
        )
        RightPaneContent()
    }
}

@Composable
fun LeftPaneContent() {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(0.4f)
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Row {
            Text(text = "Left Pane First Text Box", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Text(text = "Left Pane Second Text Box", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.size(20.dp))
        Column(Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, color = Color.Black)) {
            Text(text = "Left Pane Radio button Box  ", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp))
            val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.size(100.dp))
        Text(text = "Left Pane bottom Text Box")
    }
}

@Composable
fun RightPaneContent() {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Right Pane First Text Box")
        Spacer(Modifier.size(20.dp))
        Row {
            Text(text = "Right Pane Second Text Box", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Spacer(Modifier.size(20.dp))
            Text(text = "Right Pane Third Text Box", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite what the first answer says, as of Feb 2023 you can't use Constraint Layout in Compose Desktop, see https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/353