# Using Constraint Layout in Jetpack Compose Desktop

Tags: android, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose

I have a new Jetpack Compose desktop project in Intellij setup using the new project wizard. I would like to use ConstraintLayout like in Android, so I add the following line

```
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
```

in the build.gradle, like so:

```
sourceSets {
    val jvmMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
        }
    }
    val jvmTest by getting
}
```

However I still can't access constraint layout.

Based off the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733669/unable-to-design-ui-layout-in-desktop-for-compose) question, it seems like it is possible to use constraint layout in desktop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ConstraintLayout only works on Android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConstraintLayout is currently (Feb 2023) not implemented for Jetpack Compose Desktop