# How to align elements on Compose Row to be on the edge of the screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Hey guys I'm creating a Compose function that contains a Row and two buttons.
I want to align those buttons in a way that the first one is on start of the screen and the second one is on the end of the border.
How can I do that?
Right now, I have this:

```
@Composable
private fun TwoButtons() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Gray),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Button(
          onClick = { }
        )  {
            Text(text = "One")
        }

        Button(
            onClick = { }
        )  {
            Text(text = "Two")
        }

    }
}
```

Im getting this result:

[image: Image with two buttons on the center]

Comment: Or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68972057/15880865)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween`

[image: Row Horizontal Arrangement]

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Row(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,kotlin.Function1))