# The rationale that Text element with very long text overflows and pushes out sibling elements?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I found a problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972057/compose-wrap-text-in-row-layout-instead-of-pushing-siblings-out), but didn't understand the reason for "By default Text has a higher layout priority than Icon in order to fill the necessary space". This is very confusing and I want to understand it better. Also fixing this behavior using weight modifier for Text item seems very unintuitive for me (the attribute layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf in ConstraintLayout is better for understanding).

So the question is what is the rationale for default behavior that "Text has a higher layout priority than Icon in order to fill the necessary space"? And is there any intuitive way to understand why is it solved by using weight?

Comment: Also do note, the question you have linked to has been edited with updated info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972289/9636037

Answer (score 1):

There is no priority over any Composable over another in Jetpack Compose when measuring inside a `Layout`. Layout composable is basis for `Column`, `Row` and `Box`.

To determine measurements of a composable in a `Layout`

`measurable.measure(constraints)` is used to determine in which range(min-max) a Composable should be measured, depending on this range and content of Composable it can have width in this range.

`Constraints` is a class that determines in which range a `Measureable` should be measured.

You can check out **Constraints** section of this answer to be familiar with which size Modifier returns which `Constraints`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853

Let's say parent returned `minWidth = 0`, `maxWidth=1000`

Row `enter code here`measures Composables without `Modifier.weight()` first in order they are placed.

If `Text` composable is in the first place, in your example it is, and its content reaches parent size and since it can be measured with the range above it can occupy all the space of parent while it reaches to `Image` it forces it to be measured with `parent width - width of Text` it become smaller until becoming 0px.

But when you add `Modifier.weight()` to `Text`, Image is measured with first and since its its content is in range between Contraints it's calculated with its own size then Text covers the remaining space since it has `Modifier.weight()` with fill param is true by default.

Comment: hi thracian .. can you help me here ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview